# Using Java Predicates in MYSQL AND condition

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, predicate, criteriaquery

I have the following `java predicate` based code that gets a result list from my `MYSQL` DB:

```
Root<Person> from = query.from(Person.class);
CriteriaQuery<Person> selectQuery = query.select(from);
List<Person> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

Predicate jobPredicate = createPersonJobPredicate();
Predicate agePredicate = createPersonAgePredicate(); //currently not used

selectQuery = selectQuery.where(jobPredicate);
searchResults =entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery).setFirstResult(searchRequest.getIndex()).setMaxResults(searchRequest.getSize()).getResultList();
```

What I want to do is change the above code so that the result list has to match *both* predicates - e.g. must be `job - "doctor" AND age - 45`

I have tried combining the predicates as such below, but this always only returns the job predicate:

```
selectQuery = selectQuery.where(jobPredicate).where(agePredicate);
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> personRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);

Predicate jobPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(personRoot.get("job"), "doctor");
Predicate agePredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(personRoot.get("age"), 45);

Predicate combinedPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(jobPredicate, agePredicate);
criteriaQuery.where(combinedPredicate);
List<Person> searchResults = 
   entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```